# Capture download link while the file is downloading by firefox using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys            
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('www.example.com\mysite\')
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@value="Download"]')[0].click()
```

At this stage my program begins downloading the file I want, but if I check actual download
link while downloading the file in the firefox, it is for example:

```
 www.example.com\mysite\fsdgw?downloadid=werwqd422.jpg
```

So, I want  to collect that actual downloading link from the firefox because I wanna download it using download manager for several files with high speed.

Is it possible to get that downloading link?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this in Java.

If my html was like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="http://website.com/music/file1.mp3">
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="http://website.com/music/file2.mp3">
    </td>
  </tr>
```

My selenium code will be:

```
    List<WebElement> downloadLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("links.txt", "UTF-8");

    for(int i=0;i<downloadLinks.size();i++)
    {
      writer.writeLine(downloadLinks.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
    }

    writer.close();
```

I will then use the text file to start a burst download session in my download manager. Now it will depend whether your download manager accepts/imports txt files for downloading multiple files. You can write into a csv file if you need. I have suggested a very basic example. **Please note** that finding elements by `<a>` tag will work only if the actually download source is included in the `href` attribute. Otherwise won't help.

Comment: sorry i think you misunderstood my question. yes, the actual download link is not known by html. it is only known when i see it manually when firefox is downloading a file.

Comment: so i have to capture that download link when firefox is downloading

Comment: Yeah. I re-read your question and understood that actual download link is not in the source.

Comment: I fear in that case it will not be possible because the part where after you click on the download button, it's the native part of firefox or the browser that comes into picture which webdriver cannot do anything about.

Comment: so there is no way to capture what the browser is downloading? there should be some way, is not?

Comment: I am not sure if this works, but can you try this approach? I am assuming that your browser automatically starts downloading without asking you for the folder. When you click on the download button keep your network tab of browser dev tools open and see if there is any request+response which reveals that actual download link. If you find it for one download file, it must be the same for other download file (hopefully without any random names of the download url). You can then use a http library python has and send requests to get responses that contain the download url. Just a guess.

Comment: Wait. I think you should be able to handle the downloads page of firefox or chrome using webdriver. The downloads page shows all the download history with current downloading file. You can easily grab the links from there!

Comment: Yes, it shows the download link in the tab but not in the html. however, each file names are given randomly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49801/discussion-between-abhijeet-vaikar-and-rockpy)